# macOS Sierra - A way to move the cursor when holding down arrow key

Tags: arrow-keys, macos-sierra

Is there a way to move the cursor when I hold down the left or right arrow key.
In the former OSX versions it used to work. After I've updated to Sierra, my cursor is not moving when I hold down the arrow key.

Comment: "accessibility" is probably the reason: hold down the letter `a` and you'll see a popup with special characters based on `a` [this is on American english keyboard, others may differ]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't why the settings changed after updating from OS X El Capitan to macOS Sierra, but the following instruction worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471631/4375900

You have to open "System Preferences" then choose "Keyboard" and switch to the "Keyboard Tab".
There adjust:

1. "Keyboard Repeat" to "Fast", and
2. "Delay Until Repeat" to "Short"

and now everything is as expected.

Extra hint:
If you want an even faster key repetition, you can try to set this values:

> defaults write NSGlobalDomain KeyRepeat -int 1
>   defaults write NSGlobalDomain InitialKeyRepeat -int 10

After that you have to perform a restart.

Also mentioned here: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/issues/687

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this morning:

https://www.theguild.nl/macos-sierra-cursor-not-moving-when-holding-a-key/